# Javascript images are being repeated as number modules increases

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

I am working on dotnetnuke module development . I have developed a module . 3d hover effect, uses a javascript . The javascript is,

```
$item.find('img')
  .end()
  .append($struct)
  .find('div.slice')
  .css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')')
  .prepend($('<span class="" ></span>'));
```

If i use this images are increasing . Ex if i use 5 module s, 5 images are displaying .

Answer (score 1):

Your script is getting included and run for each instance of the module.  You can either only include the script once (perhaps by putting it in an external file and including it via the [Client Resource Management framework](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API.aspx)), or you can limit the scope of your script, to only affect the content within your module (or, do both, by creating a reusable plugin in an external script, and initializing it with a different parameter [module ID or HTML element] for each module).